# kotlin get "Type argument is not within its bounds" for recursive bounds

Tags: kotlin, generics

Get recursive "Type argument is not within its bounds" for recursive bounds when initializing an object

```
class RawType {
  
  inner class BoundRecursively<T : BoundRecursively<T>?>

  fun test() {
    
    val boundRecursively = BoundRecursively<BoundRecursively<Any>?>()
  }
}
```

the compiler gives error

```
Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'RawType.BoundRecursively<TypeVariable(T)>?'
Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'RawType.BoundRecursively<Any>?'
Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'Any'
Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'RawType.BoundRecursively<RawType.BoundRecursively<Any>?>?'
Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'RawType.BoundRecursively<RawType.BoundRecursively<Any>?>?'
Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'RawType.BoundRecursively<Any>?'
```

Any suggestion on how to fix the initialization

Answer (score 0):

When you intialize an object:

```
val boundRecursively = BoundRecursively<BoundRecursively<Any>?>()
```

First of all intializing an object with itself is very dangerous. You should be careful when doing this. Second of all you need a stopping condition, otherwise BoundRecusively will intialize an infinite number of BoundRecursively objects. You need to tell it when to stop intializing BoundRecursively objects.

Comment: Do you have any doc about stop recursive object? Thanks

Comment: The thing is you need to decide when you want to stop the object you need to check it?

Comment: I just need it once